# How to read a file from maven resources folder in GCP Cloud Function?

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, filereader

My project uses Maven with the default folder structure and when my **Google Cloud Function** is trying to read a JSON file from the resources directory (`src/main/resources`),  it fails with:

> **File Not Found** Exception

Below is my code which is standard to read from the classpath resources folder.

Any hints what could be wrong?

```
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
URL resource = classLoader.getResource("gcs-sf-dump.sql");
if (resource == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("file is not found!");
} else {
    File myFile =  new File(resource.getFile());
    String query = FileUtils.readFileToString(myFile);
}
```

Comment: did you try to name your file `classpath:gcs-sf-dump.sql"`?

Comment: no, it's just gcs-sf-dump.sql in my resources folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a `FileReader` with `BufferedReader` in my GCP Cloud Functions:

```
try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader("src/main/resources/myFile.sql"); 
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
   String fileContent = bufferedReader.lines()
                                   .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
}
```

---

Using `IOUtils` from Apache Commons (`org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`):

```
String fileContent = IOUtils.toString(getClass().getClassLoader()
       .getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/myFile.sql"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

---

> **I tried some tests with `getResourceAsStream` but no success!**

---

#### Reference:

- https://www.baeldung.com/reading-file-in-java

Comment: Seems like we have to give the path explicitly "src/main/resources/myFile.sql" and reading it via getResourceAsStream doesn't work. May be it's a limitation with Cloud Functions. Thank you.

Comment: @VinodJayachandran, really seems like a limitation. I'm glad to help you. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

For me this works:

```
 java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File("src/main/resources/file.sql");
```