# Can GCP cloud function access (write) to /src/main/resources?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a cloud function that triggers a jar, it start well until I try to write files in /src/main/resources, where I can read, in the moment that I try to write the program fails and throw an exception.

So can I write directly to /src/main/resources or I must to implement the Cloud Storage library?

References:

- https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java
- https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java11/using-cloud-storage
- [How to read a file from maven resources folder in GCP Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63991598/how-to-read-a-file-from-maven-resources-folder-in-gcp-cloud-function)

Thanks to all.

Answer (score 4):

No java code (regardless of platform) can write to that 'directory', in the sense that the *point* of that dir is that these files end up in the same place that your jar files end up, and that you read them using `MyClass.class.getResource`. If you ever write `new File("src/...")` you messed up ('src'? In production there is no 'src', obviously).

That abstraction (`MyClass.class.getResource` and friends) offer, intentionally, no way to write anything, because jar files are not meant to be writable.

The right place to store mutable data on disk is nowhere near your jar files; for end user systems, generally write in `System.getProperty("user.home")` and then from there a subdir, such as `.yourapp`, or ask the user which data directory is appropriate; different OSes have different 'flavours' (linux wants /var or ~, apple wants ~/Library/Application Support or /Library/Application Support, windows is all over the place but probably wants HOME/My Documents, etcetera), and the only one that is common amongst all of them is 'some subdir off of the user's home directory'.

For cloud in particular, you must implement the Cloud Storage Library; the actual underlying OS system your google cloud app runs on is epheremeral (it can just disappear on you and its resources are tossed into the void, if your app is written such that this is a bad thing, your app is broken).